# How to find xpath of dynamic cell value in a table

Tags: selenium, xpath

Can anyone give an example for the below scenario.
Website link: http://www.uitestingplayground.com/dynamictable
Scenario
For Chrome process get value of CPU load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are looking for the value inside the table you will need to get the number of header containing the `CPU` text since the columns order is changing in that table, as in the code below.
In case the aim element is the element below the table `//p[@class="bg-warning"]` XPath locator could be used.
Full Selenium code printing there texts could be as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)

url = 'http://www.uitestingplayground.com/dynamictable'

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

headers_locator = "//div[@role='row']//span[@role='columnheader']"
table_locator = "//div[@role='row' and(contains(.,'Chrome'))]//span[{0}]"
outer_locator = "//p[@class='bg-warning']"
cpu_column = 0

headers = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, headers_locator)))
for inx, header in enumerate(headers):
    if "CPU" in header.text:
        cpu_column = inx + 1
        break
table_locator = table_locator.format(cpu_column)
table_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, table_locator))).text
outer_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, outer_locator))).text
print("Table element text is " + table_text)
print("Outer element text is " + outer_text)
```

The output is changing from run to run, but it looks like:

```
Table element text is 7.1%
Outer element text is Chrome CPU: 7.1%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: CPU column is dynamic

Comment: I know and I resolved the problem accordingly

Comment: Can you edit in java? as I am unaware of the above language? It would be appreciate

Comment: Oh.. yes, by mistake it was unselected as answer